# How to plot 3D surface plots using Plotly in Python?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am able to get a Surface Plot using `matplotlib` with this code:

```
ax = figure.gca(projection = "3d")
ax.plot_surface(meshed_slopes, meshed_intercepts, errors.reshape(1, meshed_slopes.shape[0]), cmap = cm.autumn_r)
```

[image: Surface Plot with MatplotLib]

But when I try to do the same using **Plotly** I get a blank graph.

This is the code am using to plot the surface plot-

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import numpy as np

meshed_slopes, meshed_intercepts = np.meshgrid(slopes, intercepts)

fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(
    x = meshed_slopes,
    y = meshed_intercepts,
    z = errors.reshape(1, meshed_slopes.shape[0])
    ))

fig.show()
```

[image: Graph with Plotly]

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `x, y, z` are 2D arrays.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x, y = np.mgrid[-2:2:50j, -2:2:50j]
z = np.cos(x**2 + y**2)
fig = go.Figure([
    go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z)
])
fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the data so we can take a look I'm going to explain what plotly needs to make the plot work :

- x and y needs to be both (n,) shape and same shape
- z should be a matrix or a table with (n,n) size

I would suggest a dataframe as it might be easier for you to create everything

(Since I have low rep, I can't write comments so I'm posting this as an answear)

Comment: So if z and y are 1D arrays z should be 2D?

Comment: let's take your exemple. If x and y are 1D, the still have a length, let's hypothetically make it "n". So the shape of x and y is 1D but in reality is (n,1). So technically z should a matrix of (n,n).

Comment: Okayyy got that, Imma try it and would let you know.